# JQuery AJAX Submit Button loading indefinitely when using database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display data from a Mysql Database when clicking a Button. To do that I use AJAX.

I used [this](https://www.codexpedia.com/php/create-html-table-by-jquery-ajax-php/) Tutorial which is 90% what I'm trying to achieve. Sadly the Array is hardcoded in this example and I construct my Array using Data from my database.

So I copy and pasted the Tutorial and step by step recreated it on my site. But I'm failing on the last step. When I use the Array created by the mysqli_query function, the Submit button loads indefinitely while saying "processing".

Heres the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#personen").click(function(){
      //disable the submit button
      $(this).attr('disabled','true');
      $(this).css('cursor','progress');
      $(this).html('processing');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/widenmoos/administrator/components/com_backend/Personen_AJAX.php',
        error: function(data, error, errorThrown){
          alert(error);
          alert(errorThrown);  
        },
        success: function(data,status)
        {
          createTableByForLoop(data);
          createTableByJqueryEach(data);
          //enable the submit button
          $('#personen').css('cursor','pointer');$('#personen').html('Submit');$('#personen').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        async:   true,
        dataType: 'json'
      }); 
    });
  });

  function createTableByForLoop(data)
  {
    var eTable="<table><thead><tr><th colspan='5'>Created by for loop</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Name</th><th>Unternehmen</th><th>Gruppe</th</tr></thead><tbody>"
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
      eTable += "<tr>";
      eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Titel']+"</td>";
      eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Vorname']+"</td>";
      eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Name']+"</td>";
      eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Unternehmen']+"</td>";
      eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Gruppe']+"</td>";
      eTable += "</tr>";
    }
    eTable +="</tbody></table>";
    $('#forTable').html(eTable);
  }

  function createTableByJqueryEach(data)
  {


    var eTable="<table><thead><tr><th colspan='5'>Created by Jquery each</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Name</th><th>Unternehmen</th><th>Gruppe</th</tr></thead><tbody>"
    $.each(data,function(index, row){
      // eTable += "<tr>";
      // eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Titel']+"</td>";
      // eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Vorname']+"</td>";
      // eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Name']+"</td>";
      // eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Unternehmen']+"</td>";
      // eTable += "<td>"+String(data)[i]['Gruppe']+"</td>";
      // eTable += "</tr>";

      eTable += "<tr>";
      $.each(row,function(key,value){
        eTable += "<td>"+value+"</td>";
      });
      eTable += "</tr>";
    });
    eTable +="</tbody></table>";
    $('#eachTable').html(eTable);
  }
```

Heres the hardcoded Array:

```
<?php 

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $employees = 
    array(
            array
            (
            "Titel" => "Jack",
            "Vorname" => "Magager",
            "Name" => "$60,000",
            "Unternehmen" => "oaisjd",
            "Gruppe" => "dajskdj",
            ),

            array
            (
                "Titel" => "Jack",
                "Vorname" => "Magager",
                "Name" => "$60,000",
                "Unternehmen" => "oaisjd",
                "Gruppe" => "dajskdj",
            ),

            array
            (
                "Titel" => "Jack",
                "Vorname" => "Magager",
                "Name" => "$60,000",
                "Unternehmen" => "oaisjd",
                "Gruppe" => "dajskdj",
            )
        );

    echo json_encode($employees);
?>
```

And here's the Array derived from my database entries:

```
<?php    
    echo json_encode($employees);

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/dbConnection.php');
    header("Content-type: application/json");

    function filterTable($searchquery)  
    {   
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $searchquery);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

    $searchquery = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Name, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder"
    $searchresult = filterTable($searchquery) or die("Tabelle kann nicht angezeigt werden");

    echo json_encode($searchresult);

?>
```

See when I print_f the Arrays they are both built the same, one just has more entries

[image]

But as soon as I replace the hardcoded array with the other one the submit button just keeps loading.

Lastly, there are some German words in there. Sorry for those. But they're pretty simple:

Titel -> Title

Vorname -> First Name

Name -> Name

Unternehmen -> Company

Personen -> Persons

Anybody know whats up?

[Picture with better readable arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bG28.png)

Edited my code and now I know more but it still fails. You can find the edited JQuery Code where the old one was.

I convert it to string. But im not sure if Im doing it right so Id love some feedback. Also I added an "error" parameter. It gives out "parsererror" and "SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 1". I dont know where or how to fix the 2nd one and dont quite understand the first one either even after googling what it means. Anybody got a clue?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: That is a really hard to see image. Perhaps some more contrast?

Comment: The problem is that the button keeps loading but did the other part works?

Comment: You have key and value in the string in hardcore values in the array but in the database, the value is not the string.  "Titel" => "Jack" && "Titel" => Jack. So try to convert the value in the string and then concatenate with string in jquery.

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: I checked the console for errors but there are none.

Ill try and heighten the contrast. 

Yes the Button keeps loading while everything else works.

Ill try converting. Will come back when im done.

Comment: Your $.ajax call only has a success condition.  Shouldn't there also be a non-success condition too?  It's been a while since I did jquery but I remember there being options for non-successful lookups.

Comment: So I added the error and updated the post accordingly. Sadly Im new to JQuery and even with the Error I dont know where to start looking.

Comment: In your browser, go to developer tools and copy the JSON response that it receives and paste it in https://jsonlint.com/ to validate it.

Comment: Did it! It says the following: 

Error: Parse error on line 1:
Parse error: syntax 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

But I dont get it. You can see in my sourcecode that there isnt (or atleast shouldnt be) anything wrong with line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out guys!

As is typical. The hardest Problems are a missing semicolon.

in my PHP Code before:

```
$searchquery = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Name, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder"
```

in my PHP Code now:

```
$searchquery = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Name, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder";
```

It still doesnt quite work but now I have errors in the console and will try to figure it out myself. Thanks to everyone that tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
<?php     
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/dbConnection.php');


function filterTable($searchquery)  
{   
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $searchquery);
    return $filter_Result;
}

$searchquery = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Name, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder";
$searchresult = filterTable($searchquery) or die("Tabelle kann nicht angezeigt werden");

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($searchresult);

?>
```

Another tryout, just create a new html for it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="personen" type="button">personen</button> 
<div id="forTable" style="height: 800px; min-width: 310px"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#personen").click(function(){
  //disable the submit button
  $(this).attr('disabled','true');
  $(this).css('cursor','progress');
  $(this).html('processing');
  $.ajax({
      url: '/widenmoos/administrator/components/com_backend/Personen_AJAX.php',
    error: function(data, error, errorThrown){
      alert(error);
      alert(errorThrown);  
    },
    success: function(data,status)
    {
    console.log("Data contains: " + data.length + " elements, which are");
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
                console.log(data[i]);
        }
      createTableByForLoop(data);

      //enable the submit button
      $('#personen').css('cursor','pointer');$('#personen').html('Submit');$('#personen').removeAttr('disabled');
    },
    async:   true,
    dataType: 'json'
  }); 
});
});

  function createTableByForLoop(data)
  {
    var eTable="<table><thead><tr><th colspan='5'>Created by for loop</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Name</th>        <th>Unternehmen</th><th>Gruppe</th</tr></thead><tbody>"
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
{
  eTable += "<tr>";
  eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Titel']+"</td>";
  eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Vorname']+"</td>";
  eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Name']+"</td>";
  eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Unternehmen']+"</td>";
  eTable += "<td>"+data[i]['Gruppe']+"</td>";
  eTable += "</tr>";
}
eTable +="</tbody></table>";
$('#forTable').html(eTable);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly the result is still the same. The Button keeps loading.

Comment: i edited my answer. please send screenshot of console print

Comment: Heres the screenshots: https://imgur.com/gallery/Ywak9Ju

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured it out! It was a missing semicolon after defining $searchquery, cant make this shit up.